# R colorRampPalette to apply color values for creating new 'colored' columns

Tags: r, vector, colors

I'm trying to create a column of colors based on the values of another column. This works rather well using colorRampPalette, but I can't get it to work for V4 through V6; I think because they are binary.  How can I get a colored column for binary variables?

```
set.seed(123)
md <- data.frame(
  V1 = c('link','b','c','d','e','f','g','h'),
  V2 = sample(c('link','file'),8,replace=T),
  V3 = 1:8,
  v4=sample(c('Yes','No'),8,replace = T),
  v5=sample(c('Yes','No'),8,replace = T),
  v6=sample(c('Yes','No'),8,replace = T))
colfunc <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "grey"))
md$color <- colfunc(md$v4)
```

Comment: Can you show some successful output from V1 through V3?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
colorRampPalette(c("blue", "grey"))(length(md$V1))
colorRampPalette(c("blue", "grey"))(length(unique(md$V2)))
colorRampPalette(c("blue", "grey"))(max(md$V3))
colorRampPalette(c("blue", "grey"))(length(unique(md$v4)))
colorRampPalette(c("blue", "grey"))(length(unique(md$v5)))
colorRampPalette(c("blue", "grey"))(length(unique(md$v6)))
```

So what you have to do is to treat each column somewhat differently, and calculate an integer value for each column, since:

> colorRampPalette returns a function that takes an integer argument
>   (the required number of colors) and returns a character vector of
>   colors...

Hope it helps.